# Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy and nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-pagespeed

I get the warning "Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy" from Google Page Speed Insights.

How can I address this in nodejs?

Here's what I've done so far to fix this.

```
 app.use(express.static('client/build', { maxAge: tenMinutes }));
```

Also how do I enable text compression?

Answer (score 0):

"Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy" is expecting all of your `JS`, `CSS`, `fonts` etc. to have a cache policy of at least 30 days and ideally a year (using cache busting techniques when updates are required).

So your `maxAge` needs to be as high as possible.

Not the best with NodeJS (I would enable compression on the server itself normally) but I believe [this library would let you implement gzip](https://github.com/expressjs/compression)